# Make: missed separator in implicit rules definition

Tags: makefile, mingw, qscintilla

I install [Eric IDE](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org) on Windows 7, and it requires [QScintilla2](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/qscintilla/download) library. I tried to build that library using qmake and MinGW's make and got a make error:

```
make -f Makefile.Release
make[1]: Entering directory `/d/Install/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Qt4Qt5'
Makefile.Release:481: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/d/Install/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Qt4Qt5'
make: *** [release] Error 2
```

Makefile content:

```
####### Implicit rules

.SUFFIXES: .c .cpp .cc .cxx

{..\lexlib}.cpp{release\}.obj:: ## line 481
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Forelease\ @<<
    $<
<<
```

I'm not familiar with make, so could anyone explain what does this code mean and how to fix the error?

NOTE: when I insert \t before <<, I got the following error:

```
make[1]: *** [{..\lexlib}.cpp{release\}.obj] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/d/Install/QScintilla-gpl-2.7.2/Qt4Qt5'
make: *** [release] Error 2
```

Comment: That is not a GNU make makefile, so using MinGW make is not appropriate.  That's why you're getting that error.  I don't know anything about qmake so I can't say if that's using qmake syntax or not.  Doesn't the QScintilla documentation specify what build system you should use?

Comment: @MadScientist qmake is a tool for making a makefile from a *.pro (qt project) file, it gives me files Makefile, Makefile.Release and Makefile.Debug from qscintilla.pro file. QScintilla documentation says "Depending on the compiler you are using you may need to run nmake rather than make." I think I use g++, I have no idea whether another compiler be there.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, but that syntax is not standard make syntax and not something recognized by GNU make.  You'll have to find out what tool qmake is expecting you to use with the "makefiles" it generates on Windows, and use that tool.  After a quick look at the qmake docs, you might also try using the `-unix` option to qmake to ask it to generate a UNIX-style makefile, then using MinGW make (GNU make) with that.

Comment: -unix option has not helped me, but I found PyQt has QScintilla already, so the original goal is achieved.